# What does the M in MR stand for in the first column header of *IBuffer*?

Tags: ibuffer

When I run `M-x ibuffer`, a table of my buffers is displayed. The first column header is `MR`, and I assume the `R` stands for read only, however, I don't know what the `M` stands for. What does it stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would assume it stands for Modified. A buffer with unsaved changes will have an asterisk in this column.

Comment: Oops, I was typing my answer on my phone and didn't get a notification that you had already posted yours. Sorry about that :) @bmillare If you're going to accept an answer, it should be this one.

Answer (score 2):

`M` stands for "modified". Emacs will display a star in this column for every buffer that is visiting a modified file.

Comment: How can a buffer be both modified and read only? Aren't they mutually exclusive?

Comment: @bmillare Emacs lets you toggle read-only status of a file via `C-x C-q`, so if you modify a file and then make it read-only without saving it first, `ibuffer` will put a marker in both columns.

Comment: What's the reasoning with auto generated buffers like `*Buffer List*`, `*Messages*`, `*cider-doc*`, where I wouldn't have toggled the read-only state myself?

Comment: @bmillare Auto-generated buffers are read-only because Emacs uses them to present information *to you*. The assumption is that you don't want to edit these buffers in most cases, so Emacs prevents you from modifying them accidentally by making them read-only. I'm not an expert on this topic, but I guess these buffers are additionally marked as "modified" because they contain text that hasn't been saved to a file.